# Why does scons undo my changes to the source files?

Tags: scons

I'm trying to build an open-source project that uses scons.

I try to modify some of the source files, but when I rebuild using scons, all the changes I've made are removed.

Comment: Sounds like the "source" files you're editing are actually generated files.

Comment: I'll check that, thanks.

Comment: Are you using the SConscript() function? If so, did you set the duplicate attribute to 0? If not, then the source files are being copied to the build dir. They should be copied every time you build, but maybe this has something to do with the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, that was the problem, thanks. If you can post it as answer I'll accept it.